# Slow Confluence during SQL Script Run

Tags: mysql, sql, resources, confluence

We have an issue regarding our Atlassian Confluence system.

Basically we have a server that shares our primary load of SQL scripts which does data transformation for the production portion of the month, with our Confluence and Jira collaboration system.

Notably - we have noticed some huge slow-downs when running large scripts and trying to access Confluence pages regardless of operation on confluence (render a page, edit a page, create a page)...They all get bogged down and you end up waiting quite a few seconds for something to happen.

We just started logging the transaction levels. They are as follows:

Turned on the general and slow query logs while the script was running.

Noticed excessive activity from confluence during this time: Number of SQL statements issues rom 12:33:01pm to 13:27:16pm:

1. confluence 144,691
2. jira 6,940

For confluence that's 43.85 statement per second. 
For the confluence statements, the top were:

commit   38,286
SET autocommit=1     28,519
rollback 27,809  SET autocommit=0    27,809
**SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED     27,809

SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ  27,809**
SELECT @@session.tx_isolation    712

Main concerns are in **BOLD**

So my question is... what is Confluence doing issuing this many Transaction Level reads in that short of a time frame...?

Even internal processing looking back at DB should not be looking back at the DB that many times, whether it's a security check or to render data...

So again, what is Confluence doing? If anyone knows...is this just the way it operates? I would be interested to know if other peoples Confluence logs show relative measurements...

Why would it be slowing down ? Is it a resource - sharing issue?

Answer (score 3):

Confluence can have it's database isolation level configured at a session level, or can rely on mysql's global configuration.

My guess is that your Confluence instance is setting the isolation level once per session.  Try configuring the isolation level globally. Instructions on how to do this can be found in the [Confluence knowledge base](https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/GAtmDg)

Basically, you just need to add

> transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED

To your my.cnf file

More generally speaking, you might like to review the Confluence installation guide for MySql and make sure your database is configured the way they recommend (see https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Database+Setup+For+MySQL#DatabaseSetupForMySQL-Step3.ConfigureMySQLServer).

Comment: thank you, is there anything to worry about by setting this globally? any strange repercussions?

Comment: I'm not a DBA guru, but you will probably need to understand what other transactional requirements are needed by other clients accessing your database (if any). A transaction isolation level of "read committed" is pretty "normal", I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to add a global setting .
Please refer to this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Confluence+Does+Not+Start+with+%27MySQL+session+isolation+level+%27REPEATABLE-READ%27+is+no+longer+supported%27+Message)

According to this article, on 3.5.6 or a later version, it's suggested not to add `transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED` to my.cnf

And I checked `confluence.cfg.xml`  under atlassian/application-data/confluence,
the property `hibernate.connection.isolation` is 2 by default.(confluence V5.4.4)

So I prefer to ignore the annoying mysql log since confluence works fine:
`110 Query    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ<br>
  108 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`